# no output result when searching array or displaying array

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

I'm creating a list that allows me to input data then search or display the inputted data. For some reason I'm not able to produce an output. The problem may be the output function. How can i fix this? Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class contact{
private:
  string fn;
  string ln;
  string email;
  string number;
public:
  // Accessor and Mutator method for contacts variable
  void setfname(string f_n);
  string getfname();
  void setlname(string l_n);
  string getlname();
  void setemail(string emaila);
  string getemail();
  void setnumber(string num);
  string getnumber();
  // takes input entered for contacts
  void input();
  // display output
  void output();
  contact();

  contact(string f_n, string l_n, string emaila,string num);
};

void menu();
void EnterContact(contact contacts[], int size, int& numberUsed);
void show(contact contacts[], int sizeOfa);
int search_contacts(contact contacts[], string& lastname, int& size);

int main(){
  string opt="";
  const int MAX=2;
  int size;
  contact contacts[MAX];
  contact c[MAX];
  for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++){
    EnterContact(contacts, MAX, size);
  }
  menu();

  return 0;
}

//use these variables globally
const int MAX = 2;
contact contacts[MAX];

void EnterContact(contact contacts[], int size, int& numberUsed)
{
  char ans;
  bool done = false;
  int index = 0;
  cout << "Enter up to " << size << endl;
  while ((!done) && (index < size))
  {
    contacts[index].input();
    cout << "Do you want to add another contact?(y/n followed by Return): ";
    cin >> ans;
    if ((ans == 'y') && (ans == 'Y'))
      index++;
    else
      done = true;
  }
  numberUsed = index+1;
}

int search_contacts(contact contacts[], string& lastname, int& size)
{
  int index = 0;
  bool found = false;
  for(int index=0; index<size ; index++){
    if (lastname == contacts[index].getlname()){
      found = true;
      cout<<"found";
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!found)
    cout<<"no";
  return index;
}
void show(contact contacts[], int sizeOfa)
{
  for (int index = 0; index < sizeOfa; index++)
    contacts[index].output();
}

void menu()
{
  cout<<"\nContact Menu"<<endl;
  cout << "1. Add a New Contact. " << endl;
  cout << "2. Search for a Contact. " << endl;
  cout << "3. Delete Contact from list. " << endl;
  cout << "4. View All Contacts. " << endl;
  cout << "5. Exit the program. " << endl;
  cout << "Enter your choice: ";
  int opt; int result, a; char ans; string lastname;
  cin>>opt;
  switch (opt)
  {
  case 1: cout<<"func to Add a New Contact"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nAdd another contact";
    break;
  case 2:
    do
    {
      cout << "\nSearch contact by lastname: ";
      cin >> lastname;
      result = search_contacts(contacts, lastname, result);
      if (result == -1)
        cout << lastname << " Contact not found.\n";
      else
        contacts[result].output();

      cout << lastname << " is stored in array position "<< result << endl;
      cout << "Search again? (y/n): ";
      cin >> ans;
    } while ((ans != 'n') && (ans != 'N'));
    menu();
    break;
  case 3: cout<<"func to Delete Contact from list";
    break;
  case 4: cout<<"\nAll Contacts"<<endl;
    show(contacts, MAX);
    cout<<endl;
    menu();
    break;
  case 5: cout<<"\nContact Book is closed"<<endl;
    exit(1);
    break;
  default: cout<<"\nInvalid entry...Closing Contact Book"<<endl;
  }
}
contact::contact()
{
  fn=""; ln=""; email=""; number="";
}
contact::contact(string f_n, string l_n, string emaila,string num)
{
  fn= f_n; ln= l_n; email= emaila;number= num;
}
void contact::input()
{
  cout<<"\nFirst Name: ";
  cin>>fn;
  cout<<"Last Name: ";
  cin>>ln;
  cout<<"Email: ";
  cin>>email;
  cout<<"Phone number: ";
  cin>>number;
}

void contact::output()
{
  cout<<"\nName: "<<fn<<" "<<ln;
  cout<<"\nEmail: "<<email;
  cout<<"\nPhone number: "<<number;
  cout<<endl;
}
void contact::setfname(string f_n)
{
  fn= f_n;
}
string contact::getfname();
{
  return fn;
}
void contact::setlname(string l_n)
{
  ln= l_n;
}
string contact::getlname()
{
  return ln;
}
void contact::setemail(string emaila)
{
  email= emaila;
}
string contact::getemail()
{
  return email;
}
void contact::setnumber(string num)
{
  number= num;
}
string contact::getnumber()
{
  return number;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is how you use your menu function, try using your select menu in your main function instead of declaring it as a function. if you want to use it as a function consider using the if else statement. that should take care of your input and output.

```
int main(){
  string opt="";
  const int MAX=2;
  int size;
  contact contacts[MAX];
contact c[MAX];
for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++){
  EnterContact(contacts, MAX, size);
}
cout<<"\nContact Menu"<<endl;
cout << "1. Add a New Contact. " << endl;
cout << "2. Search for a Contact. " << endl;
cout << "3. Delete Contact from list. " << endl;
cout << "4. View All Contacts. " << endl;
cout << "5. Exit the program. " << endl;
cout << "Enter your choice: ";
int opt; int result, a; char ans; string lastname;
cin>>opt;
switch (opt)
{
case 1: cout<<"func to Add a New Contact"<<endl;
  cout<<"\nAdd another contact";
  break;
case 2:
  do
  {
    cout << "\nSearch contact by lastname: ";
    cin >> lastname;
    result = search_contacts(contacts, lastname, result);
   if (result == -1)
     cout << lastname << " Contact not found.\n";
   else
     contacts[result].output();

   cout << lastname << " is stored in array position "<< result << endl;
   cout << "Search again? (y/n): ";
   cin >> ans;
 } while ((ans != 'n') && (ans != 'N'));
 menu();
 break;
case 3: cout<<"func to Delete Contact from list";
 break;
case 4: cout<<"\nAll Contacts"<<endl;
 show(contacts, MAX);
cout<<endl;
menu();
break;
case 5: cout<<"\nContact Book is closed"<<endl;
exit(1);
break;
default: cout<<"\nInvalid entry...Closing Contact Book"<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

also you already have a function that takes care of your input you dont need to put it in a for loop in the main function.

Comment: thank you, this actually worked, sorry for the late respond, i was almost ready to give up..

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your program. The one that prevents you from displaying the contact list is this:

You have two variables named `contacts`. First, you have a local variable in `main()` declared thus:

```
  contact contacts[MAX];
```

Next, you have a global variable declared immediately after `main()` thus:

```
contact contacts[MAX];
```

Those two variables are distinct -- they are not related in any way, except coincidentally by name.  `EnterContact` writes into one of the arrays, but `show` displays the values from the other one.

You should probably move all of your global declarations to before any of your code, and remove the similarly-named declarations from `main()`.

Comment: i think you miss read the question. the user ask about the output not displaying. not how he treats his variable. your answer is irrelevant to the question

Comment: The output doesn't display  *because* he treats his variable incorrectly. Specifically, the output display routine reads from `::contacts`, while the input routine writes to `main::contacts`. If one follows the advice I list in the final paragraph, it fixes the bug about which the OP complains. Then, one must fix the bug that Mahesh found. (P.s. "misread", not "miss read".)

Comment: typo, anyway if you look closely you would realize that his global declaration about his functions is not drawing reference to EnterContact, it is drawing referencing to his menu function. the only reason why the OP would do this is unless he plans to use it somewhere else below his main.

Answer (score 0):

```
contact contacts[MAX];  

for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++){
    EnterContact(contacts, MAX, size);
}
```

I think you need to pass `i` to EnterContact function, so as to give input for each object in the array of `contacts`. As of now, you are over writing the same object on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Actually, C++ can do that.  a constant integral assigned at declaration is treated as a compile time constant in C++.

Comment: VS 2010 doesn't allow it. Let me check with all warnings on gcc.

Comment: I do this all the time in MSVC108 and MSVC10, and works on Ideone.com as well: http://ideone.com/elc7Q

Comment: I don't have VS 2010 handy. If you have can you please try this code - http://ideone.com/Liiiu on VS2010. I will correct the answer if I am wrong.

Comment: That code should not compile. `const int name = compile-time-constant-expression` is treated as a compile time constant, and function parameters are not of that form.  I haven't found validation in the spec yet though.  Anyway, his code is valid.  You may also notice that you are the only person so far to mention compiler errors, everyone else is describing runtime errors.

Comment: I don't understand what makes function parameter different from a normal intialization.

Comment: If a compiler sees `const int x = 5`, it knows that `x` will be `5` everywhere, no matter what, and so can do compile time constant math with it.  If a compiler sees `foo(const int x)`, it cannot know the value of x, and so cannot do compile-time constant math with it.  It may know that `foo` is called with `5` as a parameter in this translation unit, but cannot guarantee that no other translation unit calls `foo`, and so cannot know the value of `x`.  Theoretically, the _linker_ could do this optimization though.

Comment: § 5.19/2 : `A conditional-expression is a constant expression unless it involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression ... an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion  unless it is applied to a glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression...`  (Feb C++11 Draft)

Comment: i think you guys miss read the question. the user ask about the output not displaying. when test the code i got no error. the answer lies within the output